# Integration by parts and $dx$ notation

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

Please overview this integral evaluation:

$$ \int x^3 \arctan(x^2)dx = \frac{x^4}{4}\arctan(x^2) - \int \frac{1}{1+x^4}2x dx $$

Let's evaluate the right term:

$$\int \frac{1}{1+x^4}\color{Blue}{2x dx} = \int \frac{1}{1+x^4}\color{Blue}{dx^2} = \int y^2 \frac{1}{1+y^2} \color{Red}{dy} = ...$$

Can you explain the legitimacy of those equalities?

Yeah, I know that $(x^2)' = 2x$, but at the middle, we have the term $\frac{1}{1+x^4}$ stands by itself attached to $dx^2$. What's the meaning of that? And at the right we have $dy$ popped out of the blue (Funny, because I colored it blue).

Comment: In your integration by parts, you lost the $\frac{x^4}{4}$ factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, $d(x^2)=2xdx$. Then you can writes 
$$\int \frac{1}{1+x^4}\color{Blue}{2x dx} = \int \frac{1}{1+x^4}\color{Blue}{d(x^2)}$$ 
If $y=x^2$ then

$$\int \frac{1}{1+x^4}\color{Blue}{d(x^2)}= \int  \frac{1}{1+y^2}  dy = \arctan(y)+K= \arctan(x^2)+K,$$ $K$ constant.

Comment: Yeah ok, but I'm used to the form $\int f(x)dx$. What is the meaning of $\int f(x) d(x^2)$?

Comment: In fact there is a abuse of notation . Without prejudice to the definition $2xdx$ can be understood as $d(x^2)$ where it is understood that the change of variables $y=x^2$. What should be noted is that $2xdx$ is not the same as $dx^2$. Then, "$\int f(x)d(x^2)$ is $\int g(y)dy$".

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\int\frac{2x}{1+x^4}\,dx$$
can be evaluated through partial fraction decomposition, i.e. by noticing that:
$$\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{2}\,x+x^2}-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}\,x+x^2} = \frac{2\sqrt{2}\,x}{1+x^4}.$$
The antiderivatives of both terms in the LHS is an arctangent.

However, by noticing that $x\to\sqrt{x}$ is a smooth bijective map on $\mathbb{R}^+$, a change of variable ($x=\sqrt{u}$, so that $dx=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}\,du$) gives:
$$ \int_{0}^{t}\frac{2x}{1+x^4}\,dx = \int_{0}^{t^2}\frac{du}{1+u^2} = \arctan(t^2).$$

Comment: This was flagged as being low-quality. I would recommend making it clearer that this is a hint.